# not able to login after java update to jre1.8.181 in server

Tags: java

In our application, we use company login credentials to login, for that we have put a certificate called adserver.crt(this is the one that gives access to company credentials I guess).

After each java update, we face an issue with login at that time we run

```
cd C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin
keytool -import -keystore “c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\lib\security\cacerts” -alias <some name> -file D:\adserver.crt
```

after running this command in admin mode of command prompt we were able to login to our application using company credentials.

But after Java Update to `jre1.8.18`1(we don't have JDK in program file-->java), we are not able to login due to an authentication problem.

even I tried importing the key... still it says some expectation that the key already exists.

I tried changing the alias name ...still no use.

Please help me out with this as I am new to importing keys and server issues.

Comment: You try to Import your certificate in keystore of `jre1.8.0_144` and you use `jre1.8.0_181` at runtime?

Comment: sorry thats a typo......its 181 only

Comment: if it is a type correct it in your question

Comment: try "disable endpoint identification using a new system property: com.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification" as mentioned in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u181-relnotes-4479407.html

Comment: can you please help in setting this property to true..i mean the procedure and location

Answer (score 0):

In cacerts, there are only x509 certificates, the JVM will trust (by default). Steps to analyse

1. add the stacktrace
2. check the cert on the target address, your app tries to connect, with

   openssl s_client -connect :
3. Have a closer look on these certs, eg. With `openssl x509 -in adserver.crt -text` . Maybe the cert is expired?
4. have a look at the documentation of keytool. In your described cmd, there are some options missing...

Comment: command line was working fine with jre1.8.171...issue started after upgrading to jre1.8.181